# Set variable from external config file in ssis

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, ssis-2012

In SSIS I want to set variable value from an external configuration file. let's say I have [User::FullPath] variable and I want to set it value from an external config file so I can change my path dynamically.

Comment: Any attribute in a package can be set with a config file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-5-2-enabling-and-configuring-package-configurations?view=sql-server-ver15.  Though, normally these are used to hold static values which differ per environment.  You might also consider a foreach loop over a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified what uses you need for this "variable", and this important for the answer.
Anyway, as far as I know, it depends on your deployment model on SSIS.

- Project deployment model
- Package deployment model

> Integration Services supports two deployment models, the project deployment model and the legacy package deployment model. The project deployment model enables you to deploy your projects to the Integration Services server.

[Deploy Integration Services (SSIS) Projects and Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/legacy-package-deployment-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15)

**For Package deployment model**
[Legacy Package Deployment (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/legacy-package-deployment-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15)
See "Package Configurations".

**For Project deployment model**
[Setup Environment Variables in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4810/setup-environment-variables-in-sql-server-integration-services/)